# Maclaurin series for f(x)=arcsin(x), Im making some mistake, and don't know whats wrong

Tags: calculus

I am triyng to find the maclaurin series expansion for $f(x) = arcsin(x)$. 
I should arrive at $$ \arcsin(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{(2)(3)} + \frac{3 x^5}{(2)(4)(5)} + ... $$
I am making a mistake along the way, and I don't know what is wrong:

Using the binomial series, $$ (1 - t^2)^\frac{-1}{2} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{-1}{2}-1)\ldots(\frac{-1}{2}-k+1)}{k!}(-t^2)^k $$  I get, for the first terms:

If $k=0$, $$\frac{\frac{-1}{2}(-t^2)^0}{1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

If $k = 1$, $$\frac{\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}(-t^2) }{1} = -\frac{3t^2}{4}$$

If $ k = 2 $, $$\frac{ \frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}\frac{-5}{2}(-t^2)^2}{2!} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{5t^4}{2!}$$

If $k=3$ , $$ \frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}\frac{-5}{2}\frac{-7}{2}\frac{(-t^2)^3}{3!} = -\frac{(3)(5)(7)(t^6)}{(2)(2)(4)(6)}$$. Integrating, I get

$$ \frac{x}{2}  -\frac{3x^3}{(3)(4)}  -\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{5x^5}{(5)(2!)} -\frac{(3)(5)(7)(x^7)}{(2)(2)(4)(6) (7)} $$

Comment: the x appears after integrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominators ($k!$) are fine and the powers of $(-t^2)^k$ are fine, but your numerators are off. The value $-\frac12$ should appear in the numerator for $k=1$ (not for $k=0$), while $(-\frac12)(-\frac32)$ should appear in the numerator for $k=2$ (not for $k=1$), and so on. The numerator for $k=0$ should have $1$.

In the general formula for the $k$th term in the sum, the quantity
$$
\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{2}-1\right)\cdots\left(\frac{-1}{2}-k+1\right)\tag{*}
$$
is a product of $k$ factors; when $k=0$ the quantity (*) is interpreted as $1$.